# "ValueError: array length 293 does not match index length 975" while applying random forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, random-forest, train-test-split

I am trying to apply random forest and I am getting this error "ValueError: array length 293 does not match index length 975" . Please find the code snippet below.

Can anyone please help what I am doing wrong?
Code:

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(X, y_tmt, test_size=0.30)

def model(estimator, idx, tr_x, tr_y, ts_x, ts_y, feature_imp = True, save_importance = True, path = None):
    estimator.fit(tr_x, tr_y)
    if feature_imp:
        try:
            importance = estimator.feature_importances_
            feat_imp = pd.DataFrame({'importance':clf.feature_importances_})    
            feat_imp['feature'] = X_train.columns
            feat_imp.sort_values(by='importance', ascending=False, inplace=True)
            # feat_imp = feat_imp.iloc[:top_n]
            plt.barh(feat_imp['feature'][:20],feat_imp['importance'][:20])
            plt.show()
            if save_importance:
                feat_imp.to_csv(path)
        except:
            print ("Use a Tree based classifier")
    preds = estimator.predict(ts_x)
    preds_proba = estimator.predict_proba(ts_x)
    print ("Accuracy is: %0.2f" %accuracy_score(ts_y, preds))
    print ("Area under the curve: %0.2f" %roc_auc_score(ts_y, preds_proba[:,1]))

    fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(ts_y, preds_proba[:,1])
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
    plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
    plt.xlim([0, 1])
    plt.ylim([0, 1])
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.show()

    op = pd.DataFrame({'id': idx,
                       'truth': ts_y,
                       'probability':preds_proba[:,1],
                       'predicted':preds})
    return op

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, n_jobs = -1,max_depth=8, 
                             min_samples_leaf=256, random_state = 1, warm_start = True, 
                             criterion= 'entropy', max_features = 'sqrt')
output = model(clf, X['RecordID'], X_train,y_train, 
               X_test, y_test, 
               feature_imp=True, save_importance= False, path=None)
```

Comment: can you state at which step did the error message come up?

Comment: I got the error at last step at " output = model(clf, X['RecordID'], X_train,y_train, 
               X_test, y_test, 
               feature_imp=True, save_importance= False, path=None)

Comment: Hey i think you should trim the code down to the necessary part. The plotting functions etc are not necessary

Comment: A quick look, your X['RecordID'] is most likely different length from y_test, and this will throw an error when you try to create the dataframe `op`